# Using calloc and manually inputting chars results in a crash

Tags: c, calloc

I have this code right here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int *size;
    int i = 0;
    char buf[] = "Thomas was alone";
    size = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(buf)+1);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(buf); i++)
    {
        *(size+i) = buf[i];
        printf("%c", *(size+i));
    }
    free(size);
}
```

To my understanding calloc reserves a memspace the size of the first arg multiplied by the second, in this case 18. The length of buf is 17 and thus the for loop should not have any problems at all.

Running this program results in the expected results ( It prints Thomas was alone ), however it crashes immediately too. This persists unless I crank up the size of calloc ( like multiplied by ten ).

Am I perhaps understanding something wrongly?
Should I use a function to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Consider the following style to avoid incorrect memory size allocation: `size = calloc(n /*number of elements*/, sizeof *size);`.  No need to encode the type `size` points too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of `size` to `char`.

You are using an `int` and when you add to the pointer here `*(size+i)`, you go out of bounds.
Pointer arithmetic takes account of the type, which in you case is int not char. sizeof int is larger than char on your system.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now I understand why. I'll accept this as the answer in a couple minutes.

Comment: Certainly you mean "Change the type of `size` to `char *`".

Answer (score 3):

`int *size` means you need:

```
size = calloc(sizeof(int), sizeof(buf));
```

You allocated enough space for an array of `char`, but not an array of `int` (unless you're on an odd system where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, which is a theoretical possibility rather than a practical one).  That means your code writes well beyond the end of the allocated memory, which is what leads to the crashing.  Or you can use `char *size` in which case the original call to `calloc()` is OK.

Note that `sizeof(buf)` includes the terminal null; `strlen(buf)` does not.  That means you overallocate slightly with the `+1` term.

You could also perfectly sensibly write `size[i]` instead of `*(size+i)`.

Comment: I want to store an array of chars, not ints.
Replacing the 1 by 4 did do the trick though!

Comment: OK; then don't use `int *size;` and _do_ use `char *size;` -- and you don't need the `+1` (though it does minimal harm).  Your problem comes because you wrote `int *size` and your code therefore accesses 4 times as much memory as you allocated (under normal size assumptions).  Changing the type of `size` to `char` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate place for char array not for int array:

- char is 1 byte in memory (most often)
- int is 4 bytes in memory (most often)

so you allocate `1 * sizeof(buf) + 1` = 18 bytes
so for example in memory:

buf[0] = 0x34523
buf[1] = 0x34524
buf[2] = 0x34525
buf[3] = 0x34526
but when you use *(size + 1) you don't move pointer on 1 byte but for sizeof(int) so for 4 bytes.
So in memory it will look like:

size[0] = 0x4560
size[1] = 0x4564
size[2] = 0x4568
size[3] = 0x4572

so after few loops you are out of memory.

change `calloc(1, sizeof(buf) + 1);` to `calloc(sizeof(int), sizeof(buf) + 1);` to have enough memory.

Second think, I think is some example on which you learn how it works?
My suggestion:

- Use the same type of pointer and variable.
- when you assign diffnerent type of variables, use explicit conversion, in this example
  `*(size+i) = (int)buf[i];`